# How to get the value of the a javascript object collection?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I am having an undefined value from the object collection when is to display the message.

I should get the value and display it.

Does anybody know what is the problem or I am perhaps missing something?

link full code - https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/cq1g5dyt/1/

thanks.

```js
const ratesValue = [{
    "key": "Pound Sterling",
    "value": 1.30,
  },
  {
    "key": "Euro",
    "value": 1.30,
  },
  {
    "key": "Yen",
    "value": 142.72,
  },
  {
    "key": "Yuan",
    "value": 8.95,
  },
  {
    "key": "Swiss Franc",
    "value": 1.26,
  },
  {
    "key": "Canadian Dollar",
    "value": 1.69,
  },

];


function getCurrency() {
  let cur_type = document.getElementById('currencies').value.trim()
  // trim() method to remove whitespaces and present clean and optimal string

  let msg = cur_type ? "One US Dollar buys you " + ratesValue[cur_type] + " " + cur_type : ""
  document.getElementById("exchangerate").innerHTML = msg
}

// event handler -- put in place to be used when value selected from dropdown list.
window.onload = function () {
  getCurrency();

};
```

```html
<h1>Currency Exchange Rates to US Dollar</h1>
<!--value of an element has been changed.-->
<select id="currencies" onchange="getCurrency()">
  <option value="">Select a currency</option>
  <option>Pound Sterling</option>
  <option>Euro</option>
  <option>Yen</option>
  <option>Yuan</option>
  <option>Swiss Franc</option>
  <option>Canadian Dollar</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `ratesValue` is an *array* containing objects. To access items in an array you need to access them via their index. Currently you're trying to access a value in your array using a non-numeric string value and so you'll get `undefined`. Instead, you can use the [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method which accepts a function as an argument. The function will be called for each object inside your `ratesValue` array. If the function returns `true` for a given item, the return value for `.find()` will be that item. Using this idea, you can return `true` when the `key` property for a given item/object is equal to the selected value:

```js
const ratesValue = [{ "key": "Pound Sterling", "value": 1.30, }, { "key": "Euro", "value": 1.30, }, { "key": "Yen", "value": 142.72, }, { "key": "Yuan", "value": 8.95, }, { "key": "Swiss Franc", "value": 1.26, }, { "key": "Canadian Dollar", "value": 1.69, }, ];

function getCurrency() {
  const cur_type = document.getElementById('currencies').value.trim();
  const rateObj = ratesValue.find(obj => obj.key === cur_type);
  const msg = cur_type ? "One US Dollar buys you " + rateObj.value + " " + cur_type : "";
  document.getElementById("exchangerate").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<h1>Currency Exchange Rates to US Dollar</h1>
<select id="currencies" onchange="getCurrency()">
  <option value="">Select a currency</option>
  <option>Pound Sterling</option>
  <option>Euro</option>
  <option>Yen</option>
  <option>Yuan</option>
  <option>Swiss Franc</option>
  <option>Canadian Dollar</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

Alternatively, you could transform your `ratesValue` array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which keeps key-value pairs. The map which you create can have a keys from your the `key` property of your objects and a value from the `value` property of your objects:

```js
const ratesValue = [{ "key": "Pound Sterling", "value": 1.30, }, { "key": "Euro", "value": 1.30, }, { "key": "Yen", "value": 142.72, }, { "key": "Yuan", "value": 8.95, }, { "key": "Swiss Franc", "value": 1.26, }, { "key": "Canadian Dollar", "value": 1.69, }, ];

const ratesMap = new Map(ratesValue.map(({key, value}) => [key, value]));

function getCurrency() {
  const cur_type = document.getElementById('currencies').value.trim();
  const msg = cur_type ? "One US Dollar buys you " + ratesMap.get(cur_type)  + " " + cur_type : "";
  document.getElementById("exchangerate").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<h1>Currency Exchange Rates to US Dollar</h1>
<!--value of an element has been changed.-->
<select id="currencies" onchange="getCurrency()">
  <option value="">Select a currency</option>
  <option>Pound Sterling</option>
  <option>Euro</option>
  <option>Yen</option>
  <option>Yuan</option>
  <option>Swiss Franc</option>
  <option>Canadian Dollar</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ratesValue` is array of objects, so you have to `filter` the array to get the object you need by key .

so change this function like this

```
const value = ratesValue.find(item=>item.key === cur_type).value;
let msg = cur_type ? "One US Dollar buys you " + value + " " + cur_type : ""
```